# android database

Tags: android, sqlite

i m new in android develpment. where database foloder exists in android while creating a new db using create database command.i m using sqllite for database

Answer (score 1):

/data/data/your.package/databases

Answer (score 1):

The database should be at `/data/data/your.package.name/databases/your_db_name`

Answer (score 0):

The new database is created in the Android's internal storage in the `data/data/your.app.packagename/databases` folder.

Comment: @mudassir: where is this data folder exists while we install android

Comment: I hope you are using the Eclipse IDE. Click on the DDMS perspective, then click on File Explorer, then on data, again on data, select your app's package name, click on databases and here you can see your app's databases. Note that database will not seen if your app is not using any.

Comment: i m usering android 3.0 i can't find data folder

Comment: Have you used `openOrCreateDatabase()` method, or any other way which creates database?

Comment: @mudassir i use this reference for connection http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842 but it not create any data folder.

Comment: Database creation code is there in [Listing 2](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1763?supportItem=2). Please make sure you are executing that code?

Comment: ya i using that code and execution that code with help of http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0/page/2 i created a new java class and call the connection class

Comment: Then database is definitely not getting created. Check the Logcat for details.

Comment: is there neccessary of sqllite enviornment while executing that code

Comment: The code you are using is good. Just check where the error is. This way, you will also learn something new.